# Downloading code with git

Tags: git

I am new to git and want to download some code from GitHub, for which I have a URL: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/tree/master/doc/tutorials/content/sources/qt_visualizer

I have installed git on Ubuntu, but now I want to download all 7 files in the above URL. There appears to be no buttons on the website to download these files. So what commands do I use with git to download them from the terminal?

Comment: does `git clone https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl.git` work? It would of course clone all in pcl.git?

Answer (score 1):

There is [sparse checkout](http://jasonkarns.com/blog/subdirectory-checkouts-with-git-sparse-checkout/) in git, however you still need to clone the whole repository first, and it seems this not what you want (pcl is large package after all).

Therefore you have to download these files one by one from `raw` url:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/master/doc/tutorials/content/sources/qt_visualizer/CMakeLists.txt
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/master/doc/tutorials/content/sources/qt_visualizer/main.cpp
[...]
```

Unfortunately github doesn't allow to download whole content of `git` directory recursively (with `wget -r`).